# Unable to make any wireless connection since update to Ubuntu 22.04 (wifi, bluetooth, usb_phone)

Tags: wireless, 22.04, bluetooth, internet

I am beginner level to Ubuntu, so apologies in advance if this is presented illogically or missing details. I made the error of updating my OS to Ubuntu 22.04. I am running a dual boot windows 10/ubuntu PC with fastboot and secure booth **both turned off**. Prior to the update from 20.4 this set up was working without issue. My windows install remains unaffected.

During the update, I noticed that the internet went down and on restarting, the PC was unable to make any internet connections of any sort. I am unable to turn on WIFI, bluetooth or connect via a wired USB connection from my android phone. Although other answers suggest a driver problem, this makes me suspect a more central issue. During my searching I had wondered if this may be some incompatibility due to my VPN which I initially disconnected and  have since uninstalled, there appear to be no active connections related to it.

Similar to other questions, the wireless icon does not appear in the menu near the power button, and the wifi option setting is only found via search and then  returns "no wireless adapter is found". Wired tethering is not recognised as an internet connection, and so workarounds which rely on transmitting an internet connection fail for me. I am unable to turn on my bluetooth although the option is available in the menu, it has no effect.

I can ping local ip

```
ping 127.0.0.1
```

:

```
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
...
^C
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
19 packets transmitted, 19 received, 0% packet loss, time 18409ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.031/0.034/0.049/0.005 ms
```

No ability to ping home router or known servers

```
ping 192.168.0.1
ping 192.168.1.1
ping 8.8.8.8
```

Return

```
ping: connect: Network is unreachable


lsusb
```

,

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04e8:61f5 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Portable SSD T5
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04e8:61f5 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Portable SSD T5
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1b1c:0c14 Corsair H115i Platinum
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Restarting networking has no effect

```
sudo nmcli networking off && sudo nmcli networking on
```

:

Post restarting

```
sudo service NetworkManager status
```

:

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendo>
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-04-06 18:59:18 BST; 8min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 7266 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 38105)
     Memory: 3.4M
        CPU: 81ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─7266 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
```

Wireless adapter present, but ?no driver

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

,

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 03
       serial: 70:85:c2:bd:c1:b2
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.19.0-38-generic firmware=0. 4-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:92e00000-92e1ffff ioport:2000(size=32) memory:92e20000-92e23fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:92d00000-92d01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 00
       serial: 70:85:c2:bd:c1:b4
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.19.0-38-generic firmware=0.2-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:80 memory:92f00000-92f1ffff
```

Active connections on restart:

```
nmcli connection show --active
NAME             UUID                                  TYPE    DEVICE          
br-363ea49e9485  f7808d02-e93c-40ac-906f-bbb1e4eb1310  bridge  br-363ea49e9485 
br-b1cc7699a795  f31cbc1e-b1fb-4436-a9a5-6e935d4fe961  bridge  br-b1cc7699a795 
docker0          1091977d-1e8f-4064-8ef1-75dc6ca59672  bridge  docker0
```

Thanks David. It turns out my wireless adapter was not being claimed, and there was an issue with the driver causing both my wireless and bluetooth issues. I had to reinstall the driver for my Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 adapter.

**In case this helps save someone else a day of pain. To solve this:**

On on my Windows PC, I downloaded the following packages (amd64):

1. Linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-38-generic:
2. Linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-38:
3. Linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic:
4. linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic:
5. linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-38-generic:

I transferred these packages to the Ubuntu machine using a USB stick.

In the terminal on the Ubuntu machine, I navigated to the directory containing the downloaded .deb files.

And ran:

```
sudo apt install ./*.deb
```

this didn't work but

> sudo apt --fix broken

did

This installed the missing packages and fixed the dependency issues.

`sudo reboot`

to check new kernel is in use

```
uname -r
```

this fixed both my wireless adapter and bluetooth issues

I then had to fix my DNS settings:

I ran the following command to open the Netplan configuration file using a text editor (nano in this example):

bash

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

If the file doesn't exist, try creating it:

> sudo touch /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml sudo nano
> /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

Add the following lines to the configuration file, replacing any existing content:

> yaml Copy code:
>
> ```
> network:   version: 2
>   renderer: NetworkManager  
>   ethernets:
>     enp3s0:
>       dhcp4: yes
>       dhcp4-overrides:
>         use-dns: false
>       nameservers:
>         addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
> ```

Initially didn't work but reloaded with cloudfare dns (1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1) did

I saved the changes and exited the text editor.

I applied the new Netplan configuration with the following command:

> sudo netplan apply

Restart your network manager:

> sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

Test your internet connection by browsing websites or using ping commands.

Comment: Can you boot into an older kernel and have a wifi connection?  Any result from terminal now for `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Ping ing to yourself 127.0.0.1 really does not help.